# Timestamp fields for <initial creation> and <last update> of a task

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2013

Microsoft Project 2013:

Are there any default fields which show Time & Date when a task was FIRST CREATED, and when it was LAST EDITED ?

I would like to filter for tasks which lately have been added or updated into the whole project.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Created' field, but no updated field.  You can compare two saved copies of a file using the Compare Projects command - Report tab.  The Compare projects allows you to compare two copies (Save As) of the same file and will generate a third project file to show added tasks, deleted tasks, and changes in task or resource data.

Comment: The update solution Seen to be complicated. What about using a custom field and asking / motivating editors to update it manually?

Comment: Sure.  Anything is possible with manual intervention.  There are several spare date fields (Date1, Date2, etc) that you could ask people to enter the date of revision.